# Can you add sso using OpenConnectId to a web application that uses MVC Asp.identity?

Tags: asp.net, azure, single-sign-on

Is it possible to mix authentication types in a C# ASP.NET MVC web application hosted in Azure?

I have an ASP.NET MVC application written in C# that uses ASP.NET Identity as its authentication system.

A customer has asked if they can sign into the application using their Azure Active Directory (SSO using openconnect id).

I can recreate the application using openconnectid and assign their tenant as the AAD directory but users from my company can not log into the application because we do not exist in the customers Azure Active Directory.

We need to be able to log into the application because we perform data entry tasks for them using the web app.

Has anyone come across a similar issue?

Regards,
Graham

Answer (score 0):

You may need to show login screen with 2 possible options. You redirect the user to their respective identity provider , they get authenticated and bring back the access_token/Id_token to access application resources.

Very much like different OpenID connect providers in the same application(FB, Google, Microsoft etc) and regardless of which provider user choose to get authenticated the token is same to access resources.